How do I set the time zone format to abbreviated on Windows 10?
I've written a python script that uses strftime() from the time module. On my windows 10 computer I get the long form format for time zone  when I call strftime("%Z"), and I want to abbreviate it. I can do that in my script by parsing the first letters and joining them, but I don't want to waste time on doing that if I can just change how my system displays the time zone. In other words if I call
startup = strftime("This session began on %a - %x at %X  %Z)

I don't want it to output:
"This session began on Fri - 08/23/24 at 10:30:10 Pacific Daylight Time"
I want it to output
"This session began on Fri - 08/23/24 at 10:30:10 PDT"
without having to do a re.sub or a re.findall
I've looked through the windows 10 control panel and I can't find anything that manages the format of the time zone stamp. But to be honest, it's like a maze navigating those menus and I'm guessing it has to be in there somewhere I just need someone well versed in windows to tell me where.
I have written small algorithms that capture the first letter of the long format and joins them into an abbreviation. But I don't like wasting computation time if I can do it easier with a systems setting.

Here is what I am currently using to abbreviated the long time zone string on Windows 10. I don't need this on my Linux servers, just Windows 10
def abreviate(Sentence):
    ReFirstFind = re.findall(r'\b\w', Sentence)
    JoinTheLetters = ''.join(ReFirstFind)
    return JoinTheLetters

I'm not having any issues, using this, but I'd rather not have to use it. That is why I'm asking for any Windows guru out there to let me know if there is some config file somewhere on the system where I can have the system abbreviate like Linux does. I'm not looking for any scripts, although some of them have been cool. I just want to remove the above script and make it obsolete.

If you're willing to use pytz then something like PST = pytz.timezone("PST8PDT");  now = datetime.now(PST);  print(now.strftime( , etc, with your strftime format....

Then I'm stuck with that time zone until I go back in an manually change it. It's easier to just do this:
** 'def abbreviate(Sentence):
ReFirstFind = re.findall(r'\b\w', Sentence)
JoinTheLetters = ''.join(ReFirstFind)
return JoinTheLetters'
print (strftime("%X" -),abbreviate(strftime("%Z"))
**
Then I never have to worry about which time zone I'm in.
My question is, how do I change the time zone formating on my windows 10 computer, not how do I abbreviate a timezone.

I'm sorry about the formatting of my comment. I just joined a little while ago and I'm getting used to the mini-Markdown formats,,, Only thing is, you only get a few attempts, and I went over the limit.

Both the full and abbreviated timezone names are in the public domain. Why not create a dictionary that allows you to map full to abbreviated timezone names and vice versa

Yes, I know that. Why would I want to go through the trouble of doing that if there is a way to modify my system's timestamp? Besides it's much simplier to use the script I wrote in my response to chickity china chinese chicken. Less work, less storage space, same result.

Thank you cody gray for the excellent editing job. I'm not an editor:)

What you're looking for are abbreviations like the ones used by the IANA time zone database. Note that Windows does not use this database, so these abbreviations might be hard to access via strftime, which is limited to platform-specific functionality.
However, you can work your way around by using a zoneinfo timezone object, which in turn allows strftime to display the desired abbreviation. You'll have to use a 3rd party library though if you want to infer your machine's current time zone.
from datetime import datetime
import tzlocal  # pip install tzlocal

# let's get a zoneinfo.ZoneInfo:
localzone = tzlocal.get_localzone() # "Europe/Berlin" on my machine
now = datetime.now(localzone)

print(now.strftime("%Z"))  # "CEST" on 2024-08-26
print(now.tzinfo.key)  # IANA tz database identifier


It was worth a try, but it didn't work. Results on my windows 10 pc America/Los_Angeles, which is even worse because I can't even find the first letters of the string and turn it into PDT

@HeKaiNani I'm a bit surprised that the zoneinfo-workaround doesn't work. Did you install tzdata? Technically, time zone abbreviations are part of the IANA tz database TZif files, so there should be a way to access them. At least on my Windows machine, this works, just tested.

Yes of course,,, Or I wouldn't have gotten anything. Tell me about it. That's why I'm thinking it is Windows system thing.

@HeKaiNani yep, most likely a Windows thing. Might even be version-specific. I wrote a timezone library some time ago, Windows can be quite the challenge ^^ Anyways, sorry I couldn't help you further then.

So far yours was the only suggestion that seem plausable, and not a waste of keystrokes. So no worries, I learned a little about tzdata

Might be Windows version specific, or might be time zone specific.  I think Windows might know the abbreviation for your own time zone but not any others.  P.S.  It worked for me in Windows 11.

Mark,,, when you said, 'It worked for me in Windows 11' What exactly were you referring to? Was it abbreviated when you used strftime() with no other script to parse the timezone? If so, what module did you use?
